# WiFi-Router network connection using SIM card

Tags: router, internet

I know there are routers which support SIM cards. But can I connect a router which does not officially support SIM cards to the internet using mobile connection?

I imagine some tool which can send the mobile data through a LAN cable. Or is there a USB SIM-card standard, which works with routers?

The router I'm trying to connect to the internet through mobile data is the Archer C9 from TP-Link. Does it support USB adapters? I did not find this information on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in general but may be tough with Archer C9.

Get alternative firmware to your router. OpenWrt [supports Archer C9](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/archer-c9) with serious [limitations](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/hardware/soc/soc.broadcom.bcm53xx) unfortunately (BCM4360 not usable at all!). With other, full supported router you should get [USB dongle (modem)](https://www.google.pl/search?q=usb%20sim%20modem&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ) that will work with your SIM card and OpenWrt, then follow [this](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/3gdongle).

I have experience with OpenWrt only, not DD-WRT nor Tomato, so i used OpenWRT as example. You need to do research to establish router-firmware-modem set that will work together.

Comment: So, the support of these USB dongles is not a hardware but a software limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Archer C9 does not even include a modem.
I think there's no way to use it as you intend, not even with an usb adapter

Comment: Well then... I think of some tool which can handle SIM cards and "outputs" it to a LAN cable... basically a second router, but much smaller and without features. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your router will not do this for you on it's own.

However, whilst the following method is a little convoluted, it should allow you to share your mobile internet connection through your computer's ethernet port to the router.

First connect your computer to the internet through the mobile device.  Now open `Control Panel > Network and Sharing Centre > Change Adapter Settings`.  Right click on your mobile internet connection and select Properties.  Go to the `Sharing` tab, check the box to share the internet connection and choose your Local Area Connection from the menu.  Now you should be able to share your connection by ethernet to the router or another computer.

You can also share the wifi connection on the computer by opening an Administrator Command Prompt and typing `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="Pretty Fly For A Wifi" key=password`  This will create a hosted network called "Pretty Fly For A Wifi" with the password set as "password" (change this to whatever you want by changing the key in the command above).  Now type `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` to open the connection.  You will have to choose to share your mobile network with this hosted network by going to `Change Adapter Settings` again, as described above.

***Warning***  You cannot share a your internet connection with both the Local Area Connection AND the WiFi connection simultaneously.  You will have to share with either the ethernet port OR the wifi card - your choice but only the ethernet port will connect to the router.

Comment: Well, I was rather gonna build it without a computer and a smartphone, just using the router and maybe some adapter. But thank you for your detailed answer anyways, perhaps I or someone else is going to be able to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following device. TP-Link TL-MR3020 Mini Pocket 3G/4G Wireless Router. With this device you have to connect the USB 4G dongle. With configurations

Comment: It would be great if you could clarify how this router will help. Does it take a SIM on-board? Does it take a USB dongle? Does it connect to the Archer router using a LAN cable?